# vcpkg as submodule inside static library

Tags: c++, cmake, vcpkg

I have been using CMake with vcpkg to build my executable projects without problem. vcpkg itself is set up as a git submodule. Now I'm trying to create a statically linked library that uses the same setup.

So the project would look like this:

```
/Executable (depends on the library)
/../Library (with vcpkg dependencies)
/../../vcpkg (git submodule)
```

However when I set it up this way, with the library carrying its own vcpkg submodule, vcpkg does not seem to install the required packages. So when I call `find_package(glfw3 CONFIG REQUIRED)` CMake tells me that it can't find the package.

I want to avoid making it more complicated to use the library, if possible. Requirements to the parent project, e.g. requiring it to use vcpkg as well, would not be ideal.

Here is the library's `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
        CACHE STRING "Vcpkg toolchain file")
project(Doughnut)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

MESSAGE(STATUS "TOOLCHAIN: ${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE}")

...

# Main executable
#add_library(Doughnut STATIC ${HEADER_FILES} ${SOURCE_FILES})
#add_library(Doughnut SHARED ${HEADER_FILES} ${SOURCE_FILES})
add_library(Doughnut ${HEADER_FILES} ${SOURCE_FILES})

# Add folders
target_include_directories(Doughnut PUBLIC ${HEADER_FOLDER})
target_include_directories(Doughnut PUBLIC ${SOURCE_FOLDER})

# vcpkg autogen
find_package(glfw3 CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(Doughnut PRIVATE glfw)

...
```

And my executable's:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(DoughnutSandbox)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(DoughnutSandbox main.cpp)

add_subdirectory(external/Doughnut)
target_link_libraries(DoughnutSandbox Doughnut)
```

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: Not possible with `add_subdirectory`. May be possible with `ExternalProject`. Note that it's a responsibility of a parent project to make sure all dependencies are satisfied.